# Spring Boot register post

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(){
    GlobalData.cart.clear();
    return "login";
}
@GetMapping("/register")
public String registerGet(){
    return "register";
}
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerPost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    String password = user.getPassword();
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password));
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findById(2).get());
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);
    request.login(user.getEmail(), password);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

}

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat May 21 01:40:01 ALMT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No value present
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:143)
at com.shop.sneaker.Controllers.LoginController.registerPost(LoginController.java:43)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)

Comment: I have this error can i fix it?

Comment: There error is located here: `roles.add(roleRepository.findById(2).get());` - you are calling  `.get()` on an `Optional` that is empty - you have to check if it contains a value (`isPresent()`) or better yet use functional `.map` steps and an `orElse` variant at the end

Comment: the error should happen at:
`roles.add(roleRepository.findById(2).get());  `
You need check before the call of get()

Comment: isPresent dont work can u help with code I'm just a novice in this business a little catching up

Answer (score 0):

you get a "No Value Present" Exception since `roleRepository.findById(2)` returns an empty `Optional<Role>`.

`Optional` is a java construct that allows specifying if a value is present or not , your code simply calls `get` directly on it without checking `ifPresent`, but seems to me that you expect that a role with id 2 will exist but it doesn't. without more context we cant tell why exactly it does not exist.

more on `Optional` can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional